# With no z-index, why does an early sibling covers up a later sibling in DOM?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page with 3 DIV's: http://jsfiddle.net/AxX29/32/

With the HTML:

```
<div id="content1">foo</div>

<div id="overlay"></div>

<div id="content2">bar</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#overlay { width: 160px; height: 160px; background:yellow; 
           position: absolute; top:0; left: 0 }
```

I thought that when no element has any `z-index` defined, that means they are all `auto` (as shown by the JS in the jsfiddle), so that means the effective `z-index` is `0`, and they would appear in the order of the DOM tree traversal (probably depth first search), meaning that `overlay` should cover up `content1`, while `content2` should cover up `overlay`, but as it turns out, `overlay` covers up both `content1` and `content2`, why is that?

(I know I can put a `z-index` of `-1` to `overlay` and make it go below `content1` and `content2`, but the question is, if no `z-index` is given, why does `overlay` cover up both `content1` and `content2`?)

Comment: Your overlay has position absolute which is why it covers the rest of them which is defaulted to position static. For more info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?

Comment: @Huangism does the link you provide actually has a line that described why that was?

Comment: @動靜能量 yes as long as you read through it

Comment: @Huangism oh yes, the other source I can read through is the CSS Definitive Guide, 500 pages, can do no wrong pointing to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the CSS [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-z-index):

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

Comment: so I think the rules say: WITHIN ONE STACKING CONTEXT, the positioned elements are always on top of the non-positioned elements

Comment: that's good explanation, as we do actually see that in http://jsfiddle.net/AxX29/43/ when all elements are "positioned" (even when just `relative`), then `content2` covers up `overlay`, while `overlay` covers up `content1`

Comment: @動靜能量, yes, positioned elements are on top of the non-positioned elements, unless they have negative `z-index`.

Answer (score 4):

Giving an element `position: absolute;` removes it from the normal document flow and puts it on top of other elements.

You can add `position: relative;` to a parent div to make the absolute-positioned element positioned absolutely relative to the parent, rather than absolutely relative to the entire document.

EDIT: As you mentioned that you know already, applying `z-index` to `positioned` elements will change their depth behavior (the stacking context, as it's technically called); applying `z-index: 100; position: absolute;` to your first element, for example, would put it above the `position: absolute;` element.

Comment: but what does "add position: relative; to a parent div to make the absolute-positioned element positioned absolutely relative to the parent, rather than absolutely relative to the entire document" do?   it is no difference in http://jsfiddle.net/AxX29/41/

Comment: I think your answer might not be as complete as hoped, because what if we apply `position: relative; z-index: 1` to `#content1` and in a way, `#content1` is still in normal document flow and `#overlay` is not, and your answer would have suggested that `#overlay` still will cover up `#content1`

Comment: @動靜能量 When I get home I will try to address those situations :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at it, `auto` just means default.

The only thing to infer is that by choosing a `position:relative/absolute/static etc.` you are enabling an element to fall in to the domain of z-indexing. While it is effectively at position 0, it has more weight than a inline positioned element.

So index -1 places underneath the inline elements and index 0 or 1 does nothing.

I guess the answer is that auto/baseline is index 0, any elements with no `position:` (inline elements) live in plane 0 but have an inactive zindex. Any absolute element will overlay an inline positioned element zindexed or not.

Also worth noting is, if you absolutely position all three elements, they all overlay each other in the reverse order that they are in the DOM (last on top, first on bottom). which means the z-index weighting seems to favour the last element in the DOM.

Comment: Your last paragraph is the **Cascading** part of Cascading Style Sheets ;-)

Comment: I did think that at first. It is a cascade of sorts, but not a the cascade of CSS. That would be like. `div { background:red; } div {background: yellow} div {background: green}` the result being that when the styles cascade the div would be green. [cascade example](http://jsfiddle.net/yDLav/1/)

Comment: Right, the last style to be listed is the one that gets applied last. So if you had a red div and then a yellow div listed, the yellow div will appear on top because it places it "onto the page" (if you will) last. It's just like looking from a top-down perspective and placing blocks or LEGOs; the first LEGO piece you place will be on the bottom.

Comment: I think it's to do with the decedents of the parent element, not css. If it didn't work in this way every absolute positioned decedent would disappear under the parent. Happy to be proved wrong if you can show me an example.